# Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\Admin\SettingsController::destroy()

Tags: php, laravel

I get this error when I enter `https://example.com/admin/data/delete` in the browser. I understand the error because it does not match what is in my controller and route but I how can I handle this errors in case a user tries to do something like this.

I already created a method in my `handler.php` to handle errors but then I still get errorException pages.

PS: I have handled quite a number of errors in my code already, but is there a way to handle all Exceptions in the `handler.php` so users don't see those exceptions but the handled exception in handler.php

`Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\Admin\DataController::destroy()`

Comment: well the users wont be seeing that in production because `debug` will be false .. but yes your exception handler can handle all of this, it is its job

Comment: @lagbox  Okay at the moment, my handler handles methodNotFoundExceptions but is there a way i could use a general message for all exceptions when i set debug to `false`?

Comment: yes, your exception handler handles all the exceptions, return any response you want

Comment: The `debug` option in your `config/app.php` should be `false` then the users won't see such php errors on the page.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay, it should be false you mean? because it is set to true at the moment

Comment: @lagbox okay i got that now.. thanks a lot

Comment: yes, @LearnLaravel should be false. I updated my comment. And then we can design the page to show for that.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay, thanks a lot

Comment: @LearnLaravel, happy to help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please provide id or primary key column value of the row which you need to delete in destroy method. Destroy method will be like below:

```
function destroy($id)
{
// Delete query
}
```

Then it needs row id to delete that record.

If you are using resource route like below:

```
Route::resource('admin/data', 'Admin/DataController');
```

Then you should make a request of type **Delete** on

```
https://example.com/admin/data/delete/{id}
```